# Play pcm audio from a websocket stream in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, pcm

I am trying to play a pcm audio stream from a websocket in a react application.

On the backend I have a websocket that streams pcm audio. I was able to create a node file that would connect to the websocket pcm stream and play the audio through my computer speakers using the npm packages `websocket-stream` and `speaker`.

The issue I am having now is how to move this code over to a react application. When I try to use the `websocket-stream` package in react, the application does not compile. In addition, the `speaker` package does not seem to work in the browser. I have found a few examples of playing mp3 files in react, but none that play from a stream.

Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this github project and ported the code over to a react app: https://github.com/samirkumardas/pcm-player